# Cocos2d : Adding sprites in an array causes application to Terminate with uncaught exception

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm getting an uncaught exception error when I try to add sprites to an array, and everything looks fine to me.. I'm using MonocleStudios Simplegame project for this
 monoclestudios dot com/static/simplegame.zip

Code should be fairly self-explanatory:

`The .m file:`

```
@implementation GameScene

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
        if (self != nil) {

        Sprite * bg = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"game.png"];
        [bg setPosition:ccp(240, 60)];
        [self addChild:bg z:0];
        [self addChild:[GameLayer node] z:1];
        Sprite * bg1 = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"game.png"];
        [bg1 setPosition:ccp(211, 260)];
        [self addChild:bg1 z:0];
        //the above works fine!
        Sprite * bgX[50];
        //if comment out the next 3 lines, everything runs but I get an "unused variable" warning
        bgX[0] = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"mytree.png"];
        [bgX[0] setPosition:ccp(240,150)];
        [self addChild:bgX[0] z:0];  
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine (Cocos2D 0.7.3, if that matters with 2.1 SDK):

```
Sprite *sprites[SPRITE_COUNT];
for(int i = 0; i < SPRITE_COUNT; i++) {
    sprites[i] = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"file.png"];
    [sprites[i] setPosition: ccp(0, 0)];
    [self addChild: sprites[i] z:0];
}
```

Comment: How do I use these sprites in other functions? If I put "[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(MyFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];"
after I declare the sprites, when I try to call the sprites in MyFunction with

sprites[0] setPosition: ccp(100,100);

I get an undefined error. Where can I define Sprites so I can use it globally? (Or at least as far as the implementation file). I tried putting Sprite *sprites[50]; a couple places in the header file but I would get syntax erros in the implementation file.

Comment: I used this code myself. To make it public, put the pointer array in the interface, no the implementation.